# setTimeout() causing slowdown and not exiting properly

Tags: javascript, iframe

Clarification: The parent frame is Page X, the child frame resides within page X.
The issue is the slow behavior and never hitting the section of code that clears the interval.

I have a parent and chilframe. An object is created in the parent then I used setTimeout() in the childframe to call the parent object to add itself to an internal collection within the parent object.

The code doesn't seem to behave as intended with really slow response from the browser. Any thoughts on the issue?

Parent frame

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var Cert = new Parent();
    </script>
```

Child frame

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
        var c;
        var id = setInterval("Create()", 1000);

        function Create()
        {
            if (parent.Cert != null && parent.Cert != undefined)
            {
                c = new Child(parent.Cert, 1, null);
                clearInterval(id);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I suppose the obvious answer is that my parent object is never instantiated??? But I stepped through the code and confirmed it was.

Comment: What a vague question. No metrics, no specifics.. just "the issue" and "doesn't seem to behave as intended".

Comment: @nikklas iframe inside the parent page

Comment: Can you share the code for that as well.

Comment: @Niklas It is quite large, any particular section you are wanting to see? Plus it is an asp.net so I would need to grab the output html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `setTimeout/Interval`.  Pass it a function reference instead!

```
var id = setInterval(function () {
    Create();
}, 1000);
```

From the code you've given here, `parent` is `window`.  Is this what you intend?  There seems to be some relevant code missing here...

As for the slowdown, perhaps the function interval is too short, or it is never being satisfied? There could also be an error in the constructor for the `Child` class, which would make it so the `clearInterval` line won't ever be called.  You could consider putting a limiter out there, or wrapping your instantiation in a `try...catch` block, or moving the `clearInterval` statement above the line where you're creating your object.

Or, do all of those things:

```
    var c = null;
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        Create();
    }, 1000);

    var itr = 0;
    function Create() {
        // if it has looped more than 20 times, forget it
        if (itr > 20) {
           /* show an error message? */
           clearInterval(id);
           return false;
        }

        if (parent.Cert != null && typeof parent.Cert != 'undefined') {
            // clear the interval first
            clearInterval(id);
            // safely create object
            try {
                c = new Child(parent.Cert, 1, null);
            } catch (e) {
               /* handle exception here */
            }
        } else {
            // incrementing the interval counter
            itr++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I barely know anything about javascript terminology. If window refers to the page that the broswer window is showing, then yes.

Comment: also why do you suggest doing that instead?

Comment: Yeah, `window` is the DOM object referring to the page itself.  It is the default parent of any objects instantiated on that page.

Comment: Why do I suggest not passing a string to `setInterval`?  It is bad practice: the string is `eval`'d, which can have security issues, it can (and usually does) change the scope to something other than the developer expects, it is messy, and it makes debugging that much more complex for all of those reasons.  For all intents and purposes, consider the fact that you can pass a string to `setInterval` deprecated and obsolete.

Comment: Edited answer to add some possible solutions to the stated problem (though we really do need more details and context)